# Exchange web services - getting attachments always null

Tags: c#, .net, attachment, exchangewebservices

I have a method which accepts a `ExchangeWebServices.MessageType` parameter. I am using this variable to get the attachments from the message. When I get the contents of the attachments, it is always null. But file name is being read correctly. Below is the code I am using:

```
public void StripAttachments(MessageType fullMessage)
{
    AttachmentType[] attachments = fullMessage.Attachments;

    if (attachments != null && attachments.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (AttachmentType attachment in attachments)
        {
            if (attachment is FileAttachmentType)
            {
                FileAttachmentType file = (FileAttachmentType)attachment;

                byte[] contents = file.Content; //Always null

                try
                {
                    if(contents != null)
                    {
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\TestLocation" + file.Name, contents); 
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better method to get the attachments from a specific message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [EmailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) instead of `MessageType`

You will need to use `EmailMessage.Bind(ExchangeService, ItemId)` to populate the list of attachments and work with them, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

```cs
public void StripAttachments(ItemId id)
{
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, id)
    foreach (Attachment a in email.Attachments)
    {
        if (a is FileAttachment)
        {
            // do your thing
        }
    }
}
```

Also check out [Getting attachments by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633665%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for more of an idea.

Comment: I get the error `'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress' does not contain a definition for 'Bind'`

Comment: *facepalm* As you can see, I tried using `EmailAddress` and not `EmailMessage`. It is now working. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Not entirely sure, `EmailMessage` has been about since Exchange 2007sp1, and it looks like `MessageType` can be used for later versions. When looking into `MessageType`, I couldn't find anything useful to work with.